# Create x y array with already created array of values

Tags: javascript

I need to create a graph with some data from an API and it has to be in the following format:

```
[
        {
          x: '2020-05-31',
          y: 120
        }
        {
          x: '2020-05-30',
          y: 140
        }
        {
          x: '2020-05-29',
          y: 160
        }
      ]
```

I currently can grab some data from the API in the form of 2 arrays and I'm wondering how can I get this data in a format like the above. Example arrays of data below.

```
[120, 140, 160]
```

and

```
["2020-05-31", "2020-05-30", "2020-05-29"]
```

How do I get those values into a 2 dimensional array of objects?

Answer (score 4):

You can make use of the index parameter in [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const vals = [120, 140, 160],
      dates = ["2020-05-31", "2020-05-30", "2020-05-29"];

const res = dates.map((x, i) => ({ x, y: vals[i] }));

console.log(res);
```

Comment: really helps you're so smart

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions assume the first array is called `xArr` and the second array is called `yArr`

Solution with a for loop:

```
const newArray = [];
for(let i = 0; i<xArr.length; i++){
    newArray.push({
        x:xArr[i],
        y:yArr[i]
    }
}
```

Solution with a map:

```
const newArray = xArr.map((x, i) => ({x,y:yArr[i]}));
```